# Trying with Mocking in Unit test case

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying with Simple Multiplication application ,

```
public virtual int Multi(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

I am trying to Mock it using Moq. But in the

```
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            int a = 5;
            int b = 10;
            Mock<WebForm1> Titi = new Mock<WebForm1>();
            // WebForm1 obj = new WebForm1();
            //int  Real=  obj.Multi(a, b);
             // Titi.Setup(x => x.data()).Returns(true);
            Titi.CallBase = true;
        var data= Titi.Setup(x => x.Multi(a, b)).Returns(50);



            Assert.AreEqual(true, Titi.Object);
            //Assert.AreEqual(50, Titi.Object); 




        }
    }
}
```

Where as in the Mocking output I am getting

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<True (System.Boolean)>. Actual:<Castle.Proxies.WebForm1Proxy (Castle.Proxies.WebForm1Proxy)>
```

It means the actual & Expected are not matching, But why I am getting this error? where as it's a simple logic.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the mock correctly

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int expected = 50;
    Mock<WebForm1> mockWebForm = new Mock<WebForm1>();
    mockWebForm.Setup(x => x.Multi(a, b)).Returns(expected);

    var webForm = mockWebForm.Object;

    var data = webForm.Multi(a, b);

    Assert.AreEqual(50, data);
}
```

Normally mocks are used for dependencies.

for example say you have

```
public interface IMultiply {
    int Multiply(int a, int b);
}
```

and your web form depends on that interface

```
public class WebForm1 {
    IMultiply multiplier;
    public WebForm1(IMultiply multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    public virtual int Multi(int a, int b) {
        return multiplier.Multiply(a, b);
    }
}
```

then a unit test can look like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    //Arrange
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int expected = 50;
    var mockMultiplier = new Mock<IMultiply>();
    mockMultiplier.Setup(x => x.Multiply(a, b)).Returns(expected);

    //your web form is the system under test
    var webForm = new WebForm1(mockMultiplier.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = webForm.Multi(a, b);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: @lokanathdas has you issue been resolved? If this resolved you problem, mark it as the answer.